# Reading SQLite Database with ODBC Provider : Error with fields with float values

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, floating-point, odbc, ado

**Here is the context**

I'm building a library in VB.net able to quickly handle SQL Database datas, in windows form based front end. I'm using **ADODB Connections** and **recordsets**.
I managed to link front end to Access databases, MS SQL server, MySQL and, recently I'm working on SQLite databases to provide quick and portables SQL providers.

**Here is the problem**

As I understand it, **SQLite stores single/double/float with IEEE-7 standards**, and for exemple a stored value of 9.95 will be read as 9,94999980926514.
So when I load the record again, I can edit it (other fields), and update it. but if I try to edit the float value (lets say 9,94999980926514 > 10) then update it, then I've got an error see sample code

```
Dim LocRs as ADODB.Recordset
   LocRs.Open("SELECT ID_Montant,Mont_Value,Mont_Date FROM tMontants",SQLConnection)
   LocRs.addNew
   LocRs.("ID_Montant").Value =666
   LocRs.("Mont_Value").Value =9.95
   LocRs.("Mont_Date").Value =Date.Today
   LocRs.Update
   LocRs.close
   'No Problems'
   LocRs.open("SELECT ID_Montant,Mont_Value,Mont_Date FROM tMontants WHERE ID_Montant=666",SQLConnection)
   LocRs.Mont_Date.Value=Date.Today.AddDays(-2)
   Console.WriteLine(LocRs.("Mont_Value").Value) 'Returns 9,94999980926514'
   LocRs.Update
   LocRs.close
   'No Problem again'
   LocRs.open("SELECT ID_Montant,Mont_Value,Mont_Date FROM tMontants WHERE ID_Montant=666",SQLConnection)
   LocRs.("Mont_Value").Value=10
   LocRs.Update
   'Error : Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read. Help Code -2147217864'
```

The error code seems to be of little help.
I'm using

```
locRs.LockType = LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic
locRs.CursorType = CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
locRs.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
```

But I tried a lot of combination without success.
As for the provider I'm using [Werner ODBC Provider](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)

**I Had a similar problem with Date fields.**
When editing a field with an incomplete date like 2012-03-01 12:00:00 instead of 2012-03-01 12:00:00.000, But I corrected the problem by formating the date in it's complete form.

Now I'm stuck with this because the SQLite database stores approximates float value whether I rounded it or not before storing it with an update.

I'm guessing it's a provider problem while computing the update because I can do

```
"UPDATE tMontants SET Mont_Value = 10 WHERE ID_Montant = 666"
```

Without any problem

But I'd really like to force the recordset to work in order to integrate SQLlite solutions to every software I've deployed so far.

Thanks for your time.